# Split Tmux window simulating vim's nosplitbelow and nosplitright behaviour

Tags: tmux, split

Tmux has normal keybindings to split terminals horizontally and vertically. But it splits right and below the currently active pane. Is there a way to split the currently active pane so that the new pane spawns on the left and above the currently active pane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man tmux`:

```
     split-window [-bdfhvP] [-c start-directory] [-l size | -p percentage] [-t target-pane]
             [shell-command] [-F format]
                   (alias: splitw)
             Create a new pane by splitting target-pane: -h does a horizontal split and -v a
             vertical split; if neither is specified, -v is assumed.  The -l and -p options
             specify the size of the new pane in lines (for vertical split) or in cells (for
             horizontal split), or as a percentage, respectively.  The -b option causes the
             new pane to be created to the left of or above target-pane.  The -f option cre‐
             ates a new pane spanning the full window height (with -h) or full window width
             (with -v), instead of splitting the active pane.  All other options have the
             same meaning as for the new-window command.
```

So, putting the following lines in `~/.tmux.conf` and sourcing it would result in the desired behavior. Notice the `-b` option.

```
# pane splitting
bind -r v split-window -bh
bind -r b split-window -bv
```